# Image processor - How to dynamically change action properties (scripting?)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Say I have an action with M (many) adjustments/filters. And I run Image processor on N images.

How would I dynamically change one of the properties of the action (e.g. duotone monochrome color from Red -> Blue proportionally over the N images to process)?

Comment: You will probably have to replace the action with a script. There was a way to record an action as Action Manager script but I've no idea if it's still around. The other way is to use ScriptListener and edit that script.

Comment: Great, thx for your comment. Will check it how to do it.